# Can drone with two propellers above one another fly vertically upward without spinning?

Tags: aerodynamics, helicopter, propeller, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Basically, like the propellers setup in this image without the tail end bit:
[image]
Where the propellers will be spinning in opposite directions. This would, in theory, counteract the angular momentum to a degree right? So would this be able to fly vertically upwards without spinning?

Comment: Welcome! The answer is yes. Seems to be a duplicate of [Why does the Ka-50 (Hokum) have two main rotors, one on top of another?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32078/3201) or [How can a helicopter be designed without a tail rotor?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8642/3201)

Comment: That rear propeller does not keep the helicopter from spinning, it helps tilt the vertical lift component into a horizontal one, meaning forward and backward motion.

Comment: The rear propeller on that model is needed only because it is cheap one without cyclic controls.  Better coaxial R/C helicopters have cyclic control and so don't need anything on the tail to fly in any direction (though they are usually designed for extreme self-righting stability, so can't pitch to fly very fast, unlike full-scale coaxials which are not, and which can fly at useful speeds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because spinning in the opposite direction produces counterbalancing torque. Those rotor over rotor models adjust yaw by small variations in the speed of the rotors, so that one produces a bit more torque than another.

There are a number of large helicopters that use two main rotors to the same effect, such as the CH47 Chinook (front and rear) and the [Kamov KA31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamov_Ka-31) which uses the same rotor over rotor configuration as the model you picture.

Comment: I don't know about drones and toys, but co-axial rotor helicopters such as the Kamov Ka-31 and Ka-115 do not adjust yaw by varying the relative speeds of the rotors. The rotors are geared together and remain synchronized. It is the relative *drag* of the rotors that must be adjusted, which is easily managed via a separate swash plate for each rotor.

Comment: Varying rotor speeds is indeed how it's usually done on simpler RC models because having two motors is cheap at that scale and mechanically more sound - those models have a tendency to hit stuff, which would quickly damage the meshing. But good comment for the Kamov!

Comment: @SylvainBoisse, model rotors also have small angular momentum, so quickly accelerating them is possible. Full-scale rotors don't—moment of inertia scales with *fifth* power of diameter. So full-scale rotors can't be varied in speed with any useful precision.

Comment: The very inexpensive models have fixed pitch blades, so they can't adjust yaw by varying pitch - so they only adjust speed. True that the KA31 will do this by varying pitch instead, a more accurate method. I should have mentioned that...

Answer (score 1):

The 'fly vertically upwards' is achieved simply by increasing the rate of both motors. They still counteract each-other's torque so no spinning but now, because each rotor is angled to provide upwards force despite counter-spinning, they both provide more lift and "up she goes...."